# Corda Enterprise edition license cost

Tags: corda

Could somebody Corda Enterprise edition license model and cost? Like whether it is per user/node basis and monthly or yearly etc.
I looked at 'https://www.r3.com/corda-enterprise/' but didn't find the licese cost info.

I saw that enterprise edition also open source and code is available on Github.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should contact R3 directly (sales@r3.com) for pricing information.

According to R3:

> The platform is scalable and priced according to the specific needs of
>   the business. There are many considerations around product,
>   architecture, geography and customer profiles, which influence this
>   analysis.

Comment: Thank you Joel. I will contact them. I thought, they might have published over internet.